# TreeMap of Integers in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, treemap

I need to efficiently search ranges of integers in ColdFusion. These ranges have different lengths and they can have "holes" (they are not continuous).

I thought that a Java TreeMap called from ColdFusion would be a efficient solution. However, I sadly discovered that the TreeMap is alphabetically ordered and I need numeric order. I tried to apply the JavaCast function to the key of the map but it didn't work. Apparently, ColdFusion was expecting the key to be a String and not an Int.

Here is the sample code (without the JavaCast attempt) to illustrate my situation:

```
<!--- Create the TreeMap --->
<cfset map = createObject("java", "java.util.TreeMap").init()>

<!--- Add Ranges to it --->
<!--- From 1 to 3 return "Range 1". --->
<cfset t = StructNew()>
<cfset t.finish = JavaCast("int", 3)>
<cfset t.value = "Range 1">
<cfset map.put(1, t)><!--- This 1 is the one I tried to JavaCast --->

<!--- From 4 to 10 return "Range 2". --->
<cfset t = StructNew()>
<cfset t.finish = JavaCast("int", 10)>
<cfset t.value = "Range 2">
<cfset map.put(4, t)>

<!--- From 20 to 50 return "Range 3". --->
<cfset t = StructNew()>
<cfset t.finish = JavaCast("int", 50)>
<cfset t.value = "Range 3">
<cfset map.put(20, t)>

<!--- From 75 to 80 return "Range 4". --->
<cfset t = StructNew()>
<cfset t.finish = JavaCast("int", 80)>
<cfset t.value = "Range 4">
<cfset map.put(75, t)>

<!--- Debug. Output the Map content --->
<cfoutput>Debug - Ordered map: #map.toString()#</cfoutput><br />

<!--- Search number --->
<cfset key = 9>
<cfset entry = map.floorEntry(key)>

<!--- Debug. Output entry found --->
<cfoutput>Debug - Entry found: #entry#</cfoutput><br />

<!--- Debug. Output result --->
<cfif isNull(entry)>
    <cfoutput>Too small</cfoutput>
<cfelseif key lte entry.getValue().finish>
    <cfoutput>Debug - Result: #entry.getValue().value#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <cfoutput>Too large</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

And this is the output generated by the code above:

```
Debug - Ordered map: {1={FINISH={3},VALUE={Range 1}}, 20={FINISH={50},VALUE={Range 3}}, 4={FINISH={10},VALUE={Range 2}}, 75={FINISH={80},VALUE={Range 4}}}
Debug - Entry found: 75={FINISH={80},VALUE={Range 4}}
Debug - Result: Range 4
```

When I was expecting it to be:

```
Debug - Ordered map: {1={FINISH={3},VALUE={Range 1}}, 4={FINISH={10},VALUE={Range 2}}, 20={FINISH={50},VALUE={Range 3}}, 75={FINISH={80},VALUE={Range 4}}}
Debug - Entry found: 4={FINISH={10},VALUE={Range 2}}
Debug - Result: Range 2
```

So my question here is, what do I have to do to get the TreeMap working as I want, which is, with numeric order?

By the way, I'm using ColdFusion 9.

Thank you very much!

Comment: (Edit) Very first thing that comes to mind is you are not casting `key` values as integers. So they are probably stored as strings, meaning `floorEntry` uses string comparisons. Trying casting **all** of the `key` values as `int`'s. (I know you said it did not work, but ... it should if you cast *all* of the values.)

Comment: I'm glad you made me try that again. I was JavaCasting all values, but not the one used to search. I JavaCasted everything again and it is working as expected now. Thank you very very much for your time.

Comment: You are welcome. Good question BTW. Very succinct and even includes an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/). Wish I could up vote it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From comments)

Very first thing that comes to mind is you are not casting all of the `key` values as integers, so they are treated as strings when the `TreeMap` performs its comparisons. That would explain why `floorEntry` returns the wrong results. It is comparing [strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29), not [integers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Integer%29). Try casting **all** of the keys as integers, and it should work as expected.

```
 <cfset map.put( javacast("int", 1), t)>
 ...
 <cfset map.put( javacast("int", 75), t)>
 <cfset key = 9>
 <cfset entry = map.floorEntry( javacast("int", key) )>
```